# What's the format of timestamp to write parquet file in go

Tags: go, parquet, amazon-athena

I am trying to write a Go struct in a Parquet file and upload to S3. What format and type do I specify for timestamp parameter in the struct so that athena displays correct timestamp when reading from the parquet file.

```
type example struct {
     ID              int64  `parquet:"name=id, type=INT64"`
     CreatedAt       int64  `parquet:"name=created_at,type=TIMESTAMP_MILLIS"`
}

ex := example{}
ex.ID = int64(10)
ex.CreatedAt = time.Now().Unix()

fw, err := ParquetFile.NewLocalFileWriter("new.parquet")
pw, err := ParquetWriter.NewParquetWriter(fw, new(example), 1)
pw.Write(ex)

Upload the file new.parquet to S3
```

Reference - https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go. I created a table in Athena with int and timestamp field for the same and trying querying the table. The date is showing something like - 1970-01-18 21:54:23.751. 
which no where matches the current timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    type example struct {
        CreatedAt int64 `parquet:"name=created_at,type=TIMESTAMP_MILLIS"`
    }

    ex := example{}
    ex.CreatedAt = time.Now().UnixNano() / int64(time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println(ex.CreatedAt)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ePOlUKiT6fD

Output:

```
1257894000000
```